# convert coordinates into a point on an image in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, geography

I have this map:

[image: map]

and this coordinates:

```
lat: 42.60537919708604
lon: -96.8791615271999
```

I would like to make a point on the map using python, anyone knows how to do that?
( on windows, would be nice if you could do that with PIL or with cv2 )

expected result:

[image: result]

Comment: Are you bound to using this exact picture? If yes, do you have the geometry it's based on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this code works if you are using a map where lat and long lines are straight lines such as [image]

```
import cv2
Directory = "directory of the image" 
img = cv2.imread(Directory)
#just displaying the initial image, not needed
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#resize the image to 360,180 for lat and long locations
img = cv2.resize(img, (360, 180))
#draw a dot on the image in location: 
lat = 0 #your lat here
lat += 90
long = 0 #your longitude here 
long += 180 
img = cv2.circle(img, (x,y), 3, (0,0,255), -1) #format = (image, position, size of circle, colour)
#display the image in a window for 5 seconds (also not needed
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```